# Studying hyperchaotic ﬁnance system

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

We study the paper "Dynamic analysis and control of a new hyperchaotic finance system"

It is given the following system

$$X'=Z+(Y-\alpha)X$$
$$Y'=1-\beta Y-X^2$$
$$Z'=-X-\gamma Z$$
with initial conditions $(X(0),Y(0),Z(0))=(1,2,3)$.

Where

X: interest rate

Υ:investment demand

Z: price index

$\alpha$: savings,
$\beta$: cost per investment,
$\gamma$: the absolute value of the elasticity of demand

One of the characteristics of systems with chaotic behavior is the so-called sensitive dependence on initial conditions. So we take now $(X(0),Y(0),Z(0))=(1.001,2.001,3.001)$.
We notice that the new intial conditions differ in each coordinate by $10^{-3}$. Now I am trying to compare them on Mathematica but the plots it returns are identical. Is this possible?

```
MakePlot[{α_, β_, γ_}, {a_, b_, c_}, h_, 
  max_Integer] := 
 Module[{u, if}, 
  f[{x_, y_, z_}] := {z + (y - α)*x, 
    1 - β*y - x^2, -x - γ*z};
  u[0] = {a, b, c};
  Do[u[n + 1] = u[n] + h*f[u[n] + h/2*f[u[n]]], {n, 0, max}];
  if = Interpolation[Table[{n, u[n]}, {n, 0, max/h}]];
  Plot[if[t], {t, 0, 200}, PlotLegends -> Automatic,Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Medium]]

plot1 = MakePlot[{0.9, 0.2, 1.2}, {1, 3, 2}, 0.1, 1000 ]
plot2 = MakePlot[{0.9, 0.2, 1.2}, {1.001, 3.001, 2.001}, 0.1, 1000]
Show[{plot1, plot2}]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try with: `MakePlot[{0.13, 0.18, 0.87}, {1, 2, 3}, 0.1, 1000]` and `MakePlot[{0.13, 0.18, 0.87}, {1.001, 2.001, 3.001}, 0.1, 1000]`.

Comment: @E.Chan-López the results of the graphs are still identical no?

Comment: @E.Chan-López I can not see any difference between the plots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not identical. This is what I get:

```
MakePlot[{0.13, 0.18, 0.87}, {1, 2, 3}, 0.1, 1000]
MakePlot[{0.13, 0.18, 0.87}, {1.001, 3.001, 2.001}, 0.1, 1000]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So i have to choose a bigger interval to see the differnce

Comment: Definitely yes, you should see it at bigger intervals.